# Bash array not passed out of loop

Tags: arrays, bash

Am having this little bash script to build a custom ROM (see below)

Now the issue I encounter is the fact that I can't seem to be able to read the content of the array after the loop is done

While calling it before the new loop pass, all is good, however when the loop is done, I can not seem to be able to read it (seems to be empty)

I need to say that I am no bash expert and I usually do my code from out pal Google

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Build crDroid and optionally upload to FTP for all devices in devices.txt

#   << Start configuration >>
#crDroid_path is the location of build environment root path aka {ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}
crDroid_path=~/crDroid
#set how much RAM is used by JACK if building with
RAM=12
#CCache size
ccachesize=30G
#set if you want to save changelog file to script_path (from where the script runs) at end of build (useful to add changelog info to forums and so on... easy to find)
copy_changelog=true
#FTP config
upload_build=true
FTP_hostname="ftp://domain.tld"
FTP_username=username
FTP_password=password
#   << End configuration >>

# Specify colors utilized in the terminal
red=$(tput setaf 1)                         #  red
grn=$(tput setaf 2)                         #  green
ylw=$(tput setaf 3)                         #  yellow
blu=$(tput setaf 4)                         #  blue
cya=$(tput rev)$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 6)  #  bold cyan reversed
ylr=$(tput rev)$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 3)  #  bold yellow reversed
grr=$(tput rev)$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 2)  #  bold green reversed
txtrst=$(tput sgr0)                         #  Reset

echo "==========================================="
echo "${cya}Initiate build script - v2.9 by Gabriel Lup (gwolfu@xda)"${txtrst}
echo "==========================================="

#detect path where the script is running
script_path="`dirname \"$0\"`"              # relative
script_path="`( cd \"$script_path\" && pwd )`"  # absolutized and normalized
if [ -z "$script_path" ] ; then
    # error; for some reason, the path is not accessible
    echo "${red}Can not read run path"
    echo "Build can not continue"${txtrst}
    exit 1  # fail
fi

#check if devices.txt exists
devices=$script_path/devices.txt
if [ ! -f $devices ]; then
    echo "${red}devices.txt missing"
    echo "Build can not continue"${txtrst}
    exit 1  # fail
fi

#cleanup old changelog.txt
changelog=$script_path/changelog.txt
if [ -e $changelog ]; then
    rm -f $changelog
fi

#check if already synced
crdroid_synced=$crDroid_path/vendor/lineage/config/crdroid.mk
if [ ! -f $crdroid_synced ]; then
    echo "${ylw}Detected missing first sync... atempting first time sync..."${txtrst}
    cd $crDroid_path
    repo sync -f --force-sync --no-clone-bundle
fi

if [ ! -f $crdroid_synced ]; then
    read -p "${red}Something went wrong :( - Maybe misconfigured script!?"
    exit
fi

cd $crDroid_path
echo "${blu}Run sync?${txtrst}"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) repo sync -f --force-sync --no-clone-bundle; break;;
        No ) break;;
    esac
done

echo "${blu}Make clean build?${txtrst}"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) . build/envsetup.sh && make clean; break;;
        No ) break;;
    esac
done

#check if repopick.txt exists and execute commands from it
repopick_file=$script_path/repopick.txt
if [ -f $repopick_file ]; then
    . build/envsetup.sh
    cat $script_path/repopick.txt | while read line
    do
        $line
    done
fi

INFO=()

#Set CCache size
$crDroid_path/prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M $ccachesize

#detect android version based on crdroid.mk
rl2="`sed -n '2p' $crDroid_path/vendor/lineage/config/crdroid.mk`"
set -- "$rl2"
IFS=" "; declare -a android_major=($*) 
rl3="`sed -n '3p' $crDroid_path/vendor/lineage/config/crdroid.mk`"
set -- "$rl3"
IFS=" "; declare -a android_minor=($*) 
android=${android_major[2]}"."${android_minor[2]}

#detect crDroid version based on crdroid.mk
rl6="`sed -n '6p' $crDroid_path/vendor/lineage/config/crdroid.mk`"
set -- "$rl6"
IFS=" "; declare -a crDroid_version=($*)
crDroid=${crDroid_version[2]} 

echo "==========================================="
echo "${ylr}Setting build environment"${txtrst}
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo "Script path set to: "${grn}$script_path${txtrst}
echo "crDroid path set to: "${grn}$crDroid_path${txtrst}
echo "Jack RAM usage set to: "${grn}$RAM"GB RAM"${txtrst}
echo "Copy changelog to script path at end of build?: "${grn}$copy_changelog${txtrst}
echo "Upload complete build to FTP?: "${grn}$upload_build${txtrst}
echo "Trying to compile crDroid "${grn}$crDroid${txtrst}" based on Android "${grn}$android${txtrst}
echo "==========================================="
echo ""

echo "${ylw}Initiate build for all devices...${txtrst}" #described in devices.txt
cat $script_path/devices.txt | while read line
do
    IFS=', ' read -r -a device_uploadpath <<< "$line"
    #set device name 
    device=${device_uploadpath[0]}
    if [[ $device == *"#"* ]]; then
        device="${device//#}"
        echo "${red}Found comment (#): Skipping build for ${ylw}$device ${red}${txtrst}"
        INFO+=('1 '$device' (Reason: instruction to skip found in devices.txt)')
    else
        echo "${grn}Now building "${ylw}$device${txtrst}

        #set BuildID - aka name of the zip file from OUT folder at the end of the build  
        BuildID="crDroidAndroid-"$android"-"$(date -d "$D" '+%Y')$(date -d "$D" '+%m')$(date -d "$D" '+%d')"-"$device"-v"$crDroid"-BETA.zip"

        #Jack settings
        echo "Adding "$RAM" RAM to JACK"
        export JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xmx"$RAM"g"
        ./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin kill-server
        ./prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server

        #initiate build script and start actual build
        . build/envsetup.sh
        brunch $device

        #define upload file path
        uploadfile=$crDroid_path/out/target/product/$device/$BuildID
        echo "Checking build result status..."
        if [ -e "$uploadfile" ]; then
            echo "${grn}Seems compilation is ready!${txtrst}"
            if [ "$upload_build" = true ] ; then
                echo "${grn}Uploading new "$device" build to FTP server${txtrst}"
                echo "${ylw}Creating folder over FTP if not exist${txtrst}"
                curl $FTP_hostname/${device_uploadpath[1]}/ --user $FTP_username:$FTP_password --ftp-create-dirs
                echo "${ylw}Uploading...${txtrst}"
                curl -T $uploadfile $FTP_hostname/${device_uploadpath[1]}/ --user $FTP_username:$FTP_password
                res=$?
                if test "$res" != "0"; then
                    echo "${red}Upload of build for device $device failed with code $res${txtrst}"
                    INFO+=('1 '$device' (Reason: CURL error no.'$res' ,however compilation appears to be made)')
                else
                    INFO+=('2 '$device)
                fi
            fi

            if [ "$copy_changelog" = true ] ; then
                echo "Copy changelog file to "$script_path
                cp $crDroid_path/out/target/product/$device/system/etc/Changelog.txt $script_path/changelog.txt 
            fi
        else 
            echo "${red}Device "$device "did not produce a proper build${txtrst}"
            INFO+=('0 '$device' (Reason: unknown - better run a new build manually)')
        fi
    fi
done

echo ${grr}"Script finished with following results"${txtrst}
for i in "${INFO[@]}"
do
    #echo $i
    if [[ $i == *"0"* ]]; then
        codename=${i//0}
        echo "${red}Compilation error for device" $codename${txtrst}
    elif [[ $i == *"1"* ]]; then
        codename=${i//1}
        echo "${ylw}Warning for device" $codename${txtrst}
    else
        codename=${i//2}
        echo "${grn}Device" $codename "compiled and uploaded successfully :)${txtrst}"
    fi
done
```

This is the part that I am lost

```
echo ${grr}"Script finished with following results"${txtrst}
for i in "${INFO[@]}"
do
    #echo $i
    if [[ $i == *"0"* ]]; then
        codename=${i//0}
        echo "${red}Compilation error for device" $codename${txtrst}
    elif [[ $i == *"1"* ]]; then
        codename=${i//1}
        echo "${ylw}Warning for device" $codename${txtrst}
    else
        codename=${i//2}
        echo "${grn}Device" $codename "compiled and uploaded successfully :)${txtrst}"
    fi
```

done

Comment: The code is really long, but at first glance, this should help you: [Bash FAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). You can just write the `while` loop without the useless `cat` like this: `while read .... done < file` and you won't create a subshell. Also, quote your expansions!

Comment: yeah you are right
seems reading directly works

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Please see this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for next time. No one wants to examine million lines of code.